# Simple random walk in d=2

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $S_n$ be a simple symmetric random walk on $Z_2$

i.e. $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ where $P[X=e_i]=P[X=-e_i]=\frac{1}{4}$ for $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$.

Define $Y_i^{(1)}=X_i\cdot(1,1)$ and $Y_i^{(2)}\cdot(1,-1)$.

I showed $Y_i^{(1)}$ and $Y_i^{(2)}$ are independent.

If we let $S_n=(S_{n,1},S_{n,2})$ , then $S_{n,1}= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {Y_i^{(1)}+Y_i^{(2)}}{2}$ and $ S_{n,2}= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{Y_i^{(1)}-Y_i^{(2)}}{2}$

I want to prove $E(S_{n,1}^2+S_{n,2}^2)=n$ by using the facat $Y_i^{(1)}$ and $Y_i^{(2)}$ are independnt.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Why repost this question? To overcome the suggestions to post a question with some personal input?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, $E(S_{n,1}^2+S_{n,2}^2)=E(S_{n,1}^2)+E(S_{n,2}^2)$.
Also $4E(S_{n,1}^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nE((Y_i^{(1)}+Y_i^{(2)})^2)$
and $E((Y_i^{(1)}+Y_i^{(2)})^2)
=E((Y_i^{(1)})^2)+2E(Y_i^{(1)})E(Y_i^{(2)})+E((Y_i^{(2)})^2)$
using independence. You should be able to write down
$E(Y_i^{(1)})$, $E((Y_i^{(1)})^2)$ etc.